# Why is JS showing "undefined" in HTML

Tags: javascript, function

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head></head><body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/d2l/common/math/MathML.js?v=20.21.3.28143 "></script><script 
type="text/javascript">document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
D2LMathML.DesktopInit('https://s.brightspace.com/lib/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js? 
config=MML_HTMLorMML','https://s.brightspace.com/lib/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS- 
MML_HTMLorMML','130'); });

var add;
var cube;
var total;
var a;
var b;
function x(a, b) {
  var add = a + b;
    return add;
}

function y() {
    var cube = add * 3;
    return cube;
}

var total = x(7, 7);

if (a != b) {
    document.write(add);
}
else {
    document.write(cube);
    }

</script></body></html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/161020/vu82kc3o/2/

I'm in Intro to Web Programming and we're supposed to write a program that adds two numbers and displays the total, but if the numbers are the same then it adds them together and multiplies the sum by 3 before displaying the total. I get the first part, but when I try to add in the code for the second part it just says "undefined" in the html. The validator I used says "'document' was used before it was defined.
document.write(add);". We're supposed to use document.write in our code and the html was provided in a template we were given. Can anyone point me in the direction of what the problem is?

Comment: You never set the variables `a` or `b`. The variables `add` and `cube` are local to the functions, you can't access them outside. You never call `y`

Comment: I think you need to go back to your textbook/tutorial and reread the sections about how to call functions and variable scopes.

Comment: Will do Barmar, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Javascript! I think you are over-engineering the solution. First, let's nail down the function you are trying to write. From your question

> write a program that adds two numbers and displays the total, but if the numbers are the same then it adds them together and multiplies the sum by 3 before displaying the total.

Let's get our answer before we worry about displaying the number. We need a function with 2 arguments that performs the desired operation:

```
function customOperation(a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return (a + b) * 3; // if the two numbers are the same, sum and multiply by 3
  } else {
    return (a + b); // otherwise, just sum the numbers
  }
}
```

Now that we have a function working, we can call it, and write the response to the document:

```js
function customOperation(a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return (a + b) * 3; // if the two numbers are the same, sum and multiply by 3
  } else {
    return (a + b); // otherwise, just sum the numbers
  }
}

document.write(customOperation(3, 3)); // 18
document.write('<br>'); // line break
document.write(customOperation(4, 5)); // 9
```

Comment: Ok, obvious new guy here, but you just blew my mind. Simple pleasures for simple minds and all that. I was under the impression that you had to have variables and that document.write had to be right in line with what you're wanting to display. Being able to wait until the end and call it all together is obvious now, but totally changes my way of thinking. Thank you lucasvw!

Answer (score -1):

You're doing so many thing wrong, Please learn from the start of the basics, Initializing the variables and calling the basic function.

For Now i have update the code, You can take a look your mistakes.

```js
var add;
var cube;
var total;
var a;
var b;

function x(a, b) {
   add = a + b;
    return add;
}

function y() {
    cube = add * 3;
    return cube;
}

a=75;
b=75;
total = x(a,b);y();

if (a != b) {     
    document.write(add);
}
else {
    document.write(cube);
    }
```

Comment: So you deleted var from the functions and changed the way a,b, and total were defined. That kinda worked, but it still says "undefined" when you set a and b to the same number.  I'm trying to learn, but I can't just read a generic description and wrap my head around it. I need working examples to practice on and rework to see how it all comes together

Comment: i thought you can fix it once you learn your mistakes. Changes Updated

Comment: I am trying to do so, thank you for your time